# C# gridview column order reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to dynamically reorder gridview columns based on the needs of a user for a web application.

Say for example the default table starts with the columns A B C D ... W X Y Z.

The user brings up another table but it must have the order C D E F... Y Z A B.

The current implementation I have is the following:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="lettertable" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" NullDisplayText="" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

          <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="A" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="tlet ssA" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="B" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="tlet ssB" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="C" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="tlet ssC" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="D" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="tlet ssD" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="E" ReadOnly="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="tlet ssE" />
          ...etc
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

The codebehind involves a rather extensive set of conditionals (to account for startup vs nonstartup, vs same set of records vs across different) that look like the following:

```
         if (letchg == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < rep; i++)
                {
                    var columnMove = grid.Columns[1];
                    grid.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
                    grid.Columns.Insert((26), columnMove);
                }
            }
            if (letchg == 2)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < rep; i++)
                {
                    var columnMove = grid.Columns[1];
                    grid.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
                    grid.Columns.Insert((26), columnMove);
                }
            }
            if (letchg == -2)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < rep; i++)
                {
                    var columnMove = grid.Columns[1];
                    grid.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
                    grid.Columns.Insert((26), columnMove);
                }
            }
        }
```

There are different conditions for startup vs switching between tables, because once I reorder the columns from ABCD...WXYZ to CDEF...YZAB, it stays that way. So if I wanted to go to DEFG...ZABC, I move only one column, since it is relative. The BIG PROBLEM is that if the user hits the refresh button (creating a postback), it will resend the last operation, screwing up the whole order.

Is it possible to just reset the column order of the table every time to ABCD...WXYZ before conducting the reordering? That way it is not a relative reordering? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you even need the `if`s if all blocks are exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically add columns. For this use below code.

```
  // grid Columns with respect to their data fields
        Dictionary<string, DataControlField> gridColumns = new Dictionary<string, DataControlField>();
        for (int record = 0; record < lettertable.Columns.Count; record++)
        {
            var gridColumn = lettertable.Columns[record];
            if (gridColumn is BoundField)
            {
                var boundField = gridColumn as BoundField;
                gridColumns.Add(boundField.DataField, gridColumn);
            }
        }

        // columns new arrangement
        string columnsOrder = "BAECD";
        for(int count= lettertable.Columns.Count-1; count>-1; count--) 
        {
            // remove existig columns
            lettertable.Columns.RemoveAt(count);
        }

        // add columsn
        foreach (var columnOrder in columnsOrder)
        {
            lettertable.Columns.Add(gridColumns[columnOrder.ToString()]);
        }

        // Bind grid to show new columns
        lettertable.DataBind();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: Would further rearrangements be relative to the new order you have created above?

Comment: No rearrangements needed, new order is new new order of columns in which you want to show to User Interface.

Comment: Works very well. Thank you. For future readers, I just had to make some modifications to columnsOrder to make it an array, and it worked.